# How to prove an equilateral triangle ABC having first brocard point with angles 30, 30, 30

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, proof-without-words

Can you please help me prove an equilateral triangle having first brocard point with angles 30, 30, 30, I tried to draw the shape and to write that Cot 30= cot

Comment: That looks quite immediate: if $O$ is the center of $ABC$ then the angles formed by $OA$, $OB$ and $OC$ with the sides are all $30°$. What is your problem?

Comment: There is a missing information at the end of your question ... Moreover "Brocard" deserves a capital "B" (it was "somebody", not "something")